# I have problems with this scipy.optimize.minimize task: Newton-CG vs BFGS vs L-BFGS

Tags: python, scipy, jupyter-notebook

(SciPy optimisation: Newton-CG vs BFGS vs L-BFGS)

Consider the following area: D = [-5.10]x[0.15]. This task, given below, must be performed in
this domain.And executed in Jupyter notebook

Draw N = 100 random points uniformly distributed over D. For each point, run a local minimization of f using scipy.optimize.minimize with the following methods:
CG,BFGS,Newton-CG,L-BFGS-B. For this task, you will have to write two other functions, one that returns the Jacobian matrix of f and one that returns the Hessian matrix of f . Store the answers in an array with shape N x 6, each row of which has the following data:

(x1, y1,x2, y2,v,c),

where (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are respectively the starting and the final point of the optimization, while v is the final value of f . The final element of the row c is code of the used method, according to this correspondence: CG:1, BFGS:2, Newton-CG:3, L-BFGS-B:4

Comment: from scipy.optimize import Bounds
bounds = Bounds ([-5, 10.0], [0, 5.0])

Answer (score 0):

```
I got this code

import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import minimize
#%from numdifftools import Jacobian, Hessian

#method

mmm='CG'
#mmm='BFGS'
#mmm='Newton-CG'
#mmm='L-BFGS-B'


a=1
b=5.1/(4*np.pi**2)
c=5/np.pi
r=6
s=10
t=1/(8*np.pi)

a1=-5
b1=10
c1=0
d1=15

def f_brain(xx):
    aa=a*(xx[1]-b*xx[0]**2+c*xx[0]-r)**2+s*(1-t)*np.cos(xx[0])+s
    return aa

def fun_der(xx):
    aa1=2*a*(xx[1]-b*(xx[0]**2)+c*xx[0]-r)*(-2*b*xx[0]+c)-s*(1-t)*np.sin(xx[0])
    aa2=2*a*(xx[1]-b*(xx[0]**2)+c*xx[0]-r)
    return np.array([aa1,aa2])

def fun_hess(xx):
    b11=2*a*(c-2*b*xx[0])**2-2*b*(xx[1]-b*xx[0]**2+c*xx[1]-r)-s*(1-t)*np.cos(xx[0])
    b12=2*a*(c-2*b*xx[0])
    b21=2*a*(c-2*b*xx[0])
    b22=2*a
    return np.array([[b11,b12],[b21,b22]])

# importing libraries

x0=np.array([a1,c1])
x_bound = (a1,b1)
y_bound = (c1,d1)

result = optimize.minimize(f_brain, x0=x0, method=mmm,
                           options={'maxiter':100}, jac=fun_der(x0).all(), hess=fun_hess(x0).all(),
                           bounds=(x_bound,y_bound))


print(result) 

print("Method is "+mmm+" and the Minimum occurs at: ", result['x'])

x00=np.float64(result['x'])

print("Jacobian", fun_der(x00))

print("Hessian", fun_hess(x00))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).